# Programmatically importing products are slow to save when adding images in Magento 2.1

Tags: magento2, import, product-images, programmatically

I have a script which imports products from XML data POSTed to it from an external source into Magento 2.1.

Everything works and imports fine, however when images are added to a product, the `$product->save();` command takes around 7 seconds per image uploaded.

As a whole, it can add around 50 products without images to the system in around 4 seconds.

When images are passed in the import (hosted externally), they are downloaded locally and associated with the product before saving it.

```
$product->addImageToMediaGallery(
    $imageFile,
    $locations,
    false,
    false
);
```

I have tried using both GD and ImageMagick as the processors, but I now do not believe this to be the cause of the slowdown.

Any suggestions on where to look next to find out the source of the delay?

Comment: Have you tried timing how long it takes you to "download" the image? It's probably a good idea to have a separate script to import your images rather than having them imported in your product import.

Comment: Yes, the download happens in less than half a second... the slow down is at the point of the `$product->save();` call.

I wondered if it was to do with resizing the image for the various image sizes, but using ImageMagick actually increased the time by 300%!

Comment: Any solution for this? I have the same problem. Importing a product with an image takes 20 seconds, while without an image it takes 1 second. The images are at the root of Magento2